# MySql - i want to make thread

Tags: mysql

i have a message table see the below image

[image]

here the message table is the communication between two user about a job.

look at the msg_job_id 6, there are 5 communication about the job 6

let i am a user and my id is 4, when i view my message board that looks like

[image]

That means if there are 5 communication in between 4 and 7 about job 6 only recent message will display there

i have tried

```
SELECT id,msg_unique_id,msg_sender_id,msg_receipiant_id,msg_job_id,msg_body,created FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages where (msg_receipiant_id='4' or msg_sender_id='4')) AS T1   GROUP BY msg_sender_id,msg_receipiant_id,msg_job_id
```

it doesn't give me correct result

hope everybody understand my question

Thanks
Sanjib

Comment: no, we don't actually understand your question. To begin with did you mean 'thread'?

Comment: yes, that is thread, sorry for the typo

Comment: try to add "ORDER BY created DESC" at the end of your query, to order by latest date